# where to save application configuration

Tags: .net

we have a bunch of application which rely on configuration files; these files nowadwys reside in the same folder of the application, so (e.g.)

```
C:\Program Files\OurCompany\OurApplication
```

I understand this is the wrong folder where to store config files; where should we store these files:
- allowing end users to change their configurations
- being compliant with MS guidelines
- being consistent between the various versions of Windows from Xp up to Windows7
- being indipendent from end user language
These applications are mostly written in .NET (1.1 and 2.0), some in C++, some in VB6: so any reference to an API, a constant or anything related to these environment will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance to anyone who will help.

---

EDIT:
I'm editing this for future reference for anyone who will eventually fall here:
Pavel point is a very good point to think of; it is not applicable in our case since we have a mix of .NET, C++ and VB6 applications, but is a very good point indeed.
After Glen's suggestion, I have found these links which could be useful:
[User Data and Settings Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490855.aspx)
[Data and Settings Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb995853.aspx)
[Step-by-Step Guide to User Data and User Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742549.aspx)
[User Data & Settings (Intelliem Community)](http://share.intelliem.com/cs/blogs/danholme/archive/2008/04/30/user-data-amp-settings-connections-2008.aspx)
[Client Settings FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/rprabhu/articles/433979.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490855.aspx) gives a good tutorial on user profiles and where to store per-user settings

It includes instructions on how to use the Registry to locate the User Profile, as well as a list of the directories that live under "%Systemdrive%\Documents and Settings"

An explanation is given for each folder and recommendations for what data to put where.

Other things of interest are local and roaming profiles.

Comment: Thanks Glen: it's almost what I was looking for. By chance, do you also know how to access these folders in .NET and/or C++ and/or VB6?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [isolated](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4636/isolated-storage-in-net/3/) [storage](http://markscerri.com/2009/01/08/c-net-tutorial-8-working-with-isolated-storage/) to achieve per-user configuration.

Comment: Thanks Pavel! Isolated storage is a very good choice; unfortunately though, _in_our_case_, seems to have two major drawbacks: 1) is applicable only to .NET applications and not to C++ and VB6 ones; 2) due to his nature, files in isolated storage are not easy to find in case one wants to manually edit or replace a config file (sometimes we have to, sadly). Still, it remains a very good point, I will keep in mind in future and I upvoted it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I came looking for some information and bumped into this thread. I know it's been long time but just in case you can also take a look into: [System.Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.aspx)